# PowerShell: Moving files based on extension

Tags: powershell

The following script works but is incredibly slow. Does anyone have a faster solution?

In short, I have a folder full (4M+) of recovered files. I would like to create a subfolder for each based on extension and move the file there. As I said, the following script is incredibly slow.

```
get-childitem -file | ForEach-Object -parallel {$ext=$_.Extension; mkdir $ext; mv $_ .\$ext\} -throttlelimit 32
```

It is slow regardless of whether it runs in parallel as written or without parallel.

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

This problem occurs in versions 7 both with and without parallel being enabled. Without parallel enable in version 7, it takes about 15 seconds per file.

I have just tried the script in version 5 (without parallel, obviously) and it is processing well in excess of 100+ files per second.

So, this problem is now merely academic. Running the script in version 5 is reasonable fast and should complete the 4M+ files in less than 15 minutes at current pace.

Why does it take versions 7 15-ish seconds per file for the following script:

```
get-childitem -file | ForEach-Object {$ext=$_.Extension; mkdir $ext; mv $_ .\$ext\}
```

Comment: What does slow mean in your situation? How long does it take?

Comment: [1] how long does it take? [2] how long does each stage of your pipeline take? [3] have you tried NOT using a pipeline? [4] have you tried NOT using `foreach parallel`? that parallel stuff can actually slow things down at times ...

Comment: The problem lies somewhere in version 7. It takes about 15 seconds per file. I just ran it (without parallel) in version 5 and it is easily doing 100+ files per second.

Comment: @Reddy @ Lee_Dailey: Thanks for taking an interest but using version 5 is a reasonable solution. If you have any ideas why this is problematic in version 7, I would appreciate getting further educated.

Comment: One more question: why are you creating a folder for each file?

Comment: I am creating folders based on the file's extension. So, it isn't a folder per file. As the 4M+ files are from a file recovery activity, sorting by extension will allow quicker/easier identification of files that may be desired as part of the recovery and allow for the deletion of files that are clearly irrelevant (e.g. dll).

Comment: @Brian - thank you for the feedback. [*grin*] i see that you found one of the situations where `-Parallel` is actually worse than just one-at-a-time.

Comment: We haven't heard from you.. Did any of the given answers solve your problem? If so, please consider [accepting](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) it by clicking the **✓** icon on the left. This will help others with a similar question finding it more easily and helps motivating others to answer any questions you may have in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try to improve the speed by creating the folders first, then moving
the files in one command per each extension:

```
$extensions = Get-Childitem | Select-Object -Unique @{label='ext';expression={$_.Extension.substring(1)}}
$extensions | foreach {New-Item -ItemType directory -Name $_.ext}
$extensions | foreach {mv "*.$($_.ext)" "$($_.ext)"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you first create an array of all extensions found in the folder (without leading dot) and use robocopy to move the files while also creating the subdirectories:

```
$sourceFolder = $PSScriptRoot  # specify the path where the files are now

# get a unique array of all file extensions found in the source folder
$extensions = (Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -File | Group-Object {$_.Extension.TrimStart(".")}).Name
# loop through the extension array and have robocopy do the copying for you
foreach ($ext in $extensions) {
    $targetDir = Join-Path -Path $sourceFolder -ChildPath $ext
    robocopy $sourceFolder $targetDir "*.$ext" /MOV /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS /NC /NS /NP /R:0 /W:0 > $null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your existing command might try to create a directory with each file and extension so if you have 1000 PDF documents in the folder, it runs the command 1000 times to create a `.pdf` subfolder.

With the `-Unique` parameter of the `Select` command, it only runs that command one time for each distinct or unique file extension value to create a folder with the dot extension (e.g. `c:\ParentFolder\.pdf`).

I'd just pipe all the "unique" file extension values to another loop right over to the `New-Item` command and use the `-Force` parameter with it. Try to avoid throwing another variable into the mix if possible.

The next part I would run the `Get-ChildItem` command and loop it right into the `Move-Item` command to move the file with the matching extension to the same dot extension named subfolder.

```
Get-ChildItem -File | % { Process { $_.Extension }} | Select -Unique | % { Process { New-Item $_ -ItemType Directory -Force }};
Get-ChildItem -File | % { Process { Move-Item $_ -Destination $_.Extension -Force }};
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [New-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7.1)
- [Move-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: Also, not sure how often other or different extension values are added, but if new extension types are added frequently, then I'd add some conditional `If(test-path){}` logic around the `move-item` command since you want the folder to exist before the move of the file. Maybe all your extension types are the same for the most part and you are safe to run that first command in my example just once. Depending on your situation, minor tweaks like that are just trivial so let me know what I can help adjust to accommodate your needs if this doesn't suffice.

Comment: Keep in mind too that if disk IO is a bottle neck, throwing another threaded process may not speed things up. If it's choking on disk IO or some other shared resource, splitting the process into multiple chunks may not make it run faster so depending on your system and such, I just wanted to mention that. But PowerShell code wise, these are my quick ideas for you.